# BASH script returning command not found

Tags: bash

I am very new to bash programming and wanted to create a script that would store each result of find individually into an array. Now I want the `command` variable to expand on the statement  `MYRA=($(${Command} $1))`

```
Command = 'find . -iname "*.cpp" -o -iname "*.h"'
declare -a MYRA
    MYRA=($(${Command} $1))
echo ${#MYRA[@]}
```

However when I try this script I get the result

```
$ sh script.sh
script.sh: line 1: Command: command not found
0
```

Any suggestions on how I can fix this ?

Comment: First, you may want to include the "shell" you expect this to run as/under, such as #!/bin/bash.   I don't know if I'd use "Command" as an identifier, but I do question if you are using a single quote ' versus a single open quote `, as the open quote says to "run this as a command" while a single quote will get you the command you wanted to run as a "string" to put in your array.

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 to discuss safely storing shell commands in variables.

Comment: Also, `array=( $(find ...) )` fails miserably with filenames that contain whitespace, glob characters, or are in any other way interesting.

Comment: BTW, feel free to ask follow-up questions; some of the other tricks I used in my answer (such as reading from a NUL-delimited stream -- since NUL is the only character that can't exist in a UNIX pathname) are documented somewhere other than FAQ 50; that particular one, for instance, is touched in BashFAQ #1 (http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the below requires a `#!/bin/bash` shebang (which should come as no surprise since you're using arrays, which are a bash-only feature).

Also, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 for comprehensive discussion.

---

A best-practices implementation would look something like this:

```
# commands should be encapsulated in functions where possible
find_sources() { find . '(' -iname '*.cpp' -o -iname '*.h' ')' -print0; }

declare -a source_files
while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
  source_files+=( "filename" )
done < <(find_sources)
```

---

Now, if you *really* need to store the command in an array (maybe you're building it up dynamically), doing that would look like *this*:

```
# store literal argv for find command in array
# ...if you wanted to build this up dynamically, you could do so.
find_command=( find . '(' -iname '*.cpp' -o -iname '*.h' ')' -print0 )

declare -a source_files
while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
  source_files+=( "filename" )
done < <("${find_command[@]}")
```

Answer (score 3):

Shell assignment statements may not have whitespace around the `=`.  This is valid:

```
Command='some command'
```

This is not:

```
Command = 'some command'
```

In the second form, bash will interpret `Command` as a command name.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up however now I am getting the array size to be zero however if I replace `${Command}` with the actual command it works then